# how does TryUpdateModel in asp.net work?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms, .net-4.5, model-binding

Developing in : ASP.net web forms 4.5

I'm currently using the DynamicDataTemplateCS Nuget 
Package as in the tutorial here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/presenting-and-managing-data/model-binding/updating-deleting-and-creating-data

It enables auto-generate updatemethod and deletemethods, as and I used them and had no problem. But now I changed my data a little to display the information 
not from the table on itemtemplate field of gridview.

I looked at the code and put in print statements and it seems to go in to TryUpdateModel method and outputs true, but it doesn't update the database.

The code is like this:
on view:

```
    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="aGrid" CellPadding="10" 
    DataKeyNames="idx" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    selectMethod="aGrid_GetData" ItemType="model"
    updateMethod="aGrid_UpdateItem" AutoGenerateEditButton="true"
    deleteMethod="aGrid_DeleteItem" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true"
    onRowDataBound="aGrid_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:DynamicField DataField="poNum"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="a" HeaderText="a"/>
        <asp:DynamicField DataField="someDate" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="b" />
        <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="c"  NavigateUrl="~/yes?no={0}" />
        <asp:DynamicField DataField="e" />
        <asp:DynamicField DataField="f" />
        <asp:DynamicField DataField="g" DataformatString="{0:d}"/>
        <asp:DynamicField DataField="h" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

backend :

```
    public void aGrid_UpdateItem(int idx)
    {
        using (Context db = new Context())
        {
            model item = null;
            item = db.model.Find(idx);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("updatemethod started");

            if (item == null)
            {
                // The item wasn't found
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("item is null");

                ModelState.AddModelError("", String.Format("Item with id {0} was not found", idx));
                return;
            }
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("trying to update model");


            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(TryUpdateModel(item));
            //TryUpdateModel(item);
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("before saving changes");
                db.SaveChanges();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("after saving changes");
                // Save changes here, e.g. MyDataLayer.SaveChanges();
            }
            else
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ModelState not valid!!");
            }
        }
    }
```

I can't figure out why this is not updating.. 
I doubt that the two BoundFields "b" and "c" because actually their data is not 
from the model. I binded them outside.Anyways, it would be good to know how the TryUpdateModel works so I can figure out why this is not working.

By the way, this is the code that I binded "b" and "c" fields.
When I commented them out in the view, the update worked so they're guilty that 
TryUpdateModel is not working.

```
    protected void aGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        using (thisAction ta = new thisAction())
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {

                string str = e.Row.Cells[2].Text;
                if (str.Length > 0)
                {
                    string str2 = soa.get_str2(str);
                    e.Row.Cells[4].Text = str2;

                    string str3 = soa.get_str3(str);
                    e.Row.Cells[5].Text = str3;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

PS : I apologize for the naming.. it has some sensitive data so I had to change them

Comment: It actually works when I hide those two fields. "b" and "c" now the fields are actually guilty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this on asp.net forum and someone answered... will post this for future references, but the credit goes to Cathy Zou. Thanks Cathy.

Hi jimmythegreat,

The TryUpdateModel method applies the matching data-bound values from the web form to the data item. The data item is retrieved based on the value of the id parameter.

So, the data-bound should  be matched with the  data filed in the entity(ItemType="WingtipToys.Models.Student")

So, you shouldn't  have BoundFields  (b and c )because their data is not from the model;

I make an working sample based on tutorial you provided:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="studentsGrid"
            ItemType="WingtipToys.Models.Student" DataKeyNames="StudentID"
            SelectMethod="studentsGrid_GetData"
          UpdateMethod="studentsGrid_UpdateItem1" 
DeleteMethod="studentsGrid_DeleteItem"
            AutoGenerateEditButton="true" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true"
            AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:DynamicField DataField="StudentID" />
                <asp:DynamicField DataField="LastName" />
                <asp:DynamicField DataField="FirstName" />
                <asp:DynamicField DataField="Year" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total Credits">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label Text="<%# Item.Enrollments.Sum(en => en.Course.Credits) %>"
                            runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

CodeBehind:

```
using WingtipToys.Models;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

  public IQueryable<Student> studentsGrid_GetData()
        {
        SchoolContext db = new SchoolContext();
        var query = db.Students.Include(s => s.Enrollments.Select(e => e.Course));
        return query;
    }
    public void studentsGrid_UpdateItem(int studentID)
    {
        using (SchoolContext db = new SchoolContext())
        {
            Student item = null;
            item = db.Students.Find(studentID);
            if (item == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("",
                  String.Format("Item with id {0} was not found", studentID));
                return;
            }

            UpdateModel(item);
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }

    public void studentsGrid_DeleteItem(int studentID)
    {
        using (SchoolContext db = new SchoolContext())
        {
            var item = new Student { StudentID = studentID };
            db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Deleted;
            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("",
                  String.Format("Item with id {0} no longer exists in the database.", studentID));
            }
        }
    }
```

Best regards

Cathy

link : https://forums.asp.net/t/2133078.aspx?How+does+TryUpdateModel+work+